# Fastlane Signing issues on travis-ci (using match)

Tags: travis-ci, fastlane

I am running into an issue with fastlane on travis-ci when using match. I am able to pull the certificates, but when I get to the signing step in gym I get the following error:

```
[14:56:32]: ▸ ❌  Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'
```

I have tested locally with the same command and it works fine on my machine.

Take a look at the output:

https://gist.github.com/jwaldrip/1b0cb040b63c7f22ff19f4241db1c2e1